# JavaFX WebView HTMLElement - html code does not get parsed

Tags: java, webview, javafx

This code ignores the HTML formatting. How do I make the string be parsed as HTML in WebView?

```
HTMLElement myDiv= (HTMLElement) WebMisc.getHTMLElement(webViewPanel.getWebEngine(), "myDiv");    
myDiv.setTextContent( (new String(content)).replaceAll("\n", "<br/>") );
```

At the moment, instead of going to the next line, the WebView shows the words "<br/>".

Comment: What's the import for `HTMLElement`? I'm assuming it's some class implementing `org.w3c.dom.Element`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
Document doc = webViewPane.getWebEngine().getDocument();
for (String line : content.split("\n")) {
    myDiv.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(line));
    myDiv.appendChild(doc.createElement("br"));
}
```